# What is the best way to convert dictionary to a custom KeyValuePair type list?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a class:

```
public class MyKeyValuePair
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;

    ...
}
```

I would like to know if there's a better way of doing it than this:

```
List<MyKeyValuePair> myList;
Dictionary<string,string> dict;

foreach(var pair in dict)
{
    myList.add(new MyKeyValuePair(pair.Key, pair.Value))
}
```

Comment: welcome. this sort of question is better suited for [codereview.se]

Comment: Define better?  You could do it in one line with Linq so that's better in that it's less code, but is likely to be a bit slower.

Comment: @DanielA.White Looks off-topic for Code Review to me.

Comment: You could create an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) taking `KeyValuePair<string,string>` returning `MyKeyValuePair` (as part of the latter class), and then just do `new List<MyKeyValuePair>(dict)`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz the OPs code works. its asking for improving it.

Comment: @DanielA.White Not enough context / best practice in general. Looks off-topic there to me.

Comment: The real question would be: why? Why not just use the perfectly fine `KeyValuePair<string, string>`? If that's too much to type, a [using alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) might be fine, too.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt you might want to ask yourself, does `MyKeyValuePair` really need to _be_ a KeyValuePair or is it like a "wrapper" with additional functionality and would work just as well just _having_ a KeyValuePair (property)?

Comment: @DanielA.White oh i didn't know about Code Review, thanks

Comment: @Corak it is a kind of wrapper, but i think your implicit conversion suggestion might work better for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Corak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324205/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-dictionary-to-a-custom-keyvaluepair-type-list/61324642#comment108485822_61324205) pointed out in the comments, you could just use [`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> Struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.8) instead of making your own `MyKeyValuePair` class:

```
var list = dict
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value))
    .ToList();
```

Or better yet:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(dict)
```

Even better:

```
var list = dict.ToList();
```

The second and third approaches work because [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>()`, which is a constructor of `List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>()`. This also means it can use the [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) extension method.

The structs are also copied by *value*, not by *reference*. This is also stated in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types):

> Structure types have value semantics. That is, a variable of a structure type contains an instance of the type. By default, variable values are copied on assignment, passing an argument to a method, and returning a method result. In the case of a structure-type variable, an instance of the type is copied. For more information, see [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types).

Comment: Or just `var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(dict)`. `Dictionary<string, string>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()`, which a constructor of `List<...>` takes. And KvPs are structs, so they get fully copied by value, not by reference, so it's creating new instances by itself. --- come to think of it, `dict.ToList()` would do the trick, too. ^_^;

Answer (score 4):

Linq approach

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict; //input
List<MyKeyValuePair> result = dict.Select(x => new MyKeyValuePair() { 
                                                 Key = x.Key, 
                                                 Value = x.Value}).ToList();
```

Comment: @fubo omg I'm blind, sorry for the mixup, you've got my vote :)